# Django 500 Error page doesn't load CSS file

Tags: python, html, css, django, http-status-code-500

The 500 error handler template won't load CSS even if typed everything correctly.
For example, my home template loads CSS properly using the same method
Here's the 500.html template

```
    <html>
        <head>
            {%load static%}
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
            <title>500</title>
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}"/>
        
        </head>
        
        <body>
         html code here
        </body>
        
        </html>
```

This should load the style.css file from the static folder

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}"/>`

In the terminal it looks like everything is OK, but it still doesn't load.

`"GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 734`

if I try to access 127.0.0.1:8000/static/main.css (the one for the homepage) it shows it how it should

if I try to access 127.0.0.1:8000/static/style.css it gives me an error

I don't know if it matters but I'm doing this with DEBUG = False

Edit: I solved the error by running the server with `py manage.py runserver --insecure`
At this point I wonder how could I get around this if I wanted to host the website on a server? Why doesn't it load static files for error pages without running the server like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `manage.py runserver` command starts the Django development server, a server which it is **not** intended to be used in production and which, as a result, stops to serve the static files when `DEBUG=FALSE`.

As you point out in your edit, you can bypass this security by using the `--insecure` option when you start the server ([see the documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#runserver)). But this is clearly an insecure and inefficient solution.

So you can serve the static files with a real HTTP server (some examples and tutorials are given [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/deployment/)) or you can have a look to the very popular [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) application to help you doing that.

Answer (score 0):

this is usually i render django template tags : {% load static %}. sometimes pay attention to spaces. and also, I include static on the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Keep DEBUG=TRUE in setting.py

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/

Static files are served via Django on when DEBUG is True.